# GDAL GetGeoTransform() precision

Tags: python, gdal, qgis, rasterio, pyqgis

I need to read extent of tif file with larger number of signs after point.

Example:
when I open tif image in QGis I got these numbers:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXBmA.png)

but with GDAL GetGeoTransform() I lose two last digits:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNWHY.png)

I also tried to use rasterio .bounds and it works the same for me.

I need all those signs after point to be saved. How could I do it using GDAL (or any other libraries if it can solve the issue)?

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't that basically the exact same number but visualized differently? You're at the very limit of what float64 can handle. Compare it for example to the next and previous possible value (by +/ the significand) at:  https://float.exposed/0x403ecd500e10a9fd

Comment: @RutgerKassies those are different, indeed, even with using the way you have shown. Also, in my case it`s critical to lose those digits

Comment: Compare the value you get with the significand increased or decrease with 1 (eg `4166393391000060` or `4166393391000062`). Storing the value you show (from QGIS and GDAL) as a float64 will always result in `30.8020027914699205951` since that's the closest possible value. GDAL seems to just round it to where it's significant, and QGIS doesn't. It still looks like a visualization thing to me, not actual storage of the value.